# Find a colider through script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an inventory script and I need to find a game object and get its component which is a collider then enable it. Here is my code can you show me where I went wrong.

```
public GameObject[] Inventory = new GameObject[3];
public Image[] InventorySlots = new Image[3];
public GameObject Ending;

private void Start()
{
   Ending = GameObject.Find("End Determination Object").GetComponent<Collider2D>; //this doesn't work
}

public void AddStoryItem(GameObject item)
{
    bool itemAdded = false;
    //to put items in inventory
    for (int i = 0; i < Inventory.Length; i++)
    {
        //check for empty slot
        if (Inventory[i] == null)
        {
            //place item
            Inventory[i] = item;
            InventorySlots[i].overrideSprite = item.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;
            Debug.Log(item.name + " hey you got an item");
            itemAdded = true;
            item.SendMessage("Store");
            break;
        }
    }
    //inventory full
    if (!itemAdded)
    {
        Debug.Log("it's full");
        //enable collider here

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the [`unityscript` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) explicitly states that you should not use it for questions about C# Unity code (on the basis that Unityscript is its own language).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this:

```
public GameObject Ending;

private void Start()
{
   Ending = GameObject.Find("End Determination Object").GetComponent<Collider2D>; //this doesn't work
}
```

It won't work because `Ending` is a type of `GameObject` but you are assigning `Collider2D` to it when you did `Ending = GameObject.Find("End Determination Object").GetComponent<Collider2D>;`

This would have worked (because `GameObject.Find` returns a type of `GameObject`):

```
Ending = GameObject.Find("End Determination Object");
```

But since you want to find a `Collider2D` not `GameObject` change

```
public GameObject Ending;
```

to

```
public Collider2D Ending;
```

Now you can do: `Ending = GameObject.Find("End Determination Object").GetComponent<Collider2D>();`.

*Notice `()` I added at the end because `GetComponent` is a function.*